# Automating SQL scripts in Toad for Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, automation, toad

I'm not a DBA, so bear with me.

I've scheduled tasks through Toad's automation designer, but this uses Windows task scheduler. It's using Oracle 12c.

How can I ensure my scripts execute on time without running a local machine with scheduled tasks? Can this be done without additional software? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider posting your question on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what those scripts do.

However, if they can be rewritten into stored procedures, then you could schedule them as **database jobs** using either `DBMS_SCHEDULER` (or `DBMS_JOB`, which is simpler but still quite usable) package.

As a matter of fact, `DBMS_SCHEDULER` can even run your operating system scripts, using `job_type => 'external_script'`. Read documentation for more info.

See if it helps.